FastAPI--background_tasks did not raise exception successfully when I use httpx.AsyncClient
My code looks like:
async def run():
   background_tasks.add_task(do_upload, upload_url, headers, data)

async def do_upload(upload_url, headers, data):
   try:
      # The post request continues longer than 1s, to show the exception I change timeout to 1s
      async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=1) as client:
          logging.info("start")
          response = await client.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=data)
          logging.info("end")
   except Exception as ret:
      logging.error(f"An error occurred: {ret}")

However, I did not catch the error info. just print "start"
expected: raise exception and echo "An error occurred: {some info like timeout}"

Corrected the typo first httpx.AsyncClinet to httpx.AsyncClient
